# How to jump out of any surrounds?

Tags: evil, cursor, motion

Not just parenthesis, but any surround. We are given the advantage of a pair being made and the cursor conveniently placed within. That's only 1/2 the procedure; what about jumping out?

Previous (which covers only parens): [how-do-i-jump-out-of-enclsing-parentheses](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/14556/how-do-i-jump-out-of-enclosing-parentheses)

Evil mode in Spacemacs. Thanks.

EDIT: okay, 'pair' instead of 'surround' keyword:

[A elisp function to jump between matched pair](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/13222/a-elisp-function-to-jump-between-matched-pair)

Answer (score 1):

[smartparens](https://github.com/Fuco1/smartparens) (described in the other answer you refer to) works well with quotes, too, just like inside parens.  It's very useful even outside of lisps -- on just about anything that has open and close semantics, including strings and blocks.

For your case, use `C-M-u` (`sp-backward-up-sexp`) to jump **u**p and out to the front of the string you're in.  And if you want to jump to the right side instead, do the prior and then `C-M-f` (`sp-forward-sexp`) to get there.

Comment: Thanks. Parents and quotes yes. XML tag no. Will want to keybind what you provide - as in IDEs, just hit TAB or similar to finish and move on.